# Add margin-top to headings and reduce their margin-bottom

Tags: feature-request, design

**TL;DR**: Headings currently have a CSS `margin-bottom` value, but not a `margin-top` value resulting in a distance to the following paragraph. I propose to add a `margin-top` and reduce the `margin-bottom` of headings.

**Example picture (current situation):**
On the left a screenshot of an answer with a heading (level 2), on the right backgrounds added for visualization.

[image: Example visualization of margin]

**Example picture (with proposed margins):**
Same text but with the `margin-top` set to `1em` and the `margin-bottom` reduced to `0.3em`. Notice how the heading seems to be attached to the following paragraph instead of the previous one.

[image: Example visualization of proposed change]

---

**Long story**: For context, I recently gave a longer [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55576899/5627599) with multiple headings and subheadings. I noticed that the margin on headings looks odd as they seem to be attached to the previous paragraphs instead of the following one.

After checking the CSS I found out, that the value of the `margin-bottom` is set to `1em`, resulting in a distance of `21px` to the bottom for level 1 headings while they have a distance of `15px` to the previous paragraph. In my opinion, a `margin-top` should be added and the `margin-bottom` should be reduced to improve the readability.

---

More text examples of all heading levels. All headings have a distance of `15px` to the previous paragraph.

> Paragraph with text.
>
> ## Heading, level 1, 21px margin bottom
>
> Paragraph with text.
>
> ### Heading, level 2, 19px margin bottom
>
> Paragraph with text.
>
> #### Heading, level 3, 17px margin bottom
>
> Paragraph with text.

Comment: Good suggestion, your proposed change makes the structure much clearer.

Comment: I agree that it adds a good visual hierarchy to the text, making it clearer to discern what the heading is attached to.

Comment: This was something that was annoying me yesterday. I resorted to just using bold formatting for headings with line breaks to add desired spacing above and below the text.

Comment: But nothing actually changed right? At least not on meta site?